# Changing Ceph to store number of data copies

Tags: ceph

Currently I am using replication for data placement and think I am using three copies, which I think is the default. How do I change ceph config to store 4 copies on different nodes in different chassis? Also, would this change impact anything existing on ceph?

Thanks,
Kampton

Answer (score 0):

To increase the number of replicas you can set the pool size according to your requirements:

```
ceph osd pool set size 4
```

The placement of the copies (chassis) is called failure domain. This is configured in the [ruleset](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/operations/crush-map/) you're using. You can change the ruleset for a given pool:

```
# get current ruleset for given pool
ceph osd pool get iscsi-pool crush_rule 
crush_rule: replicated_rule

# dump ruleset
ceph osd crush rule dump replicated_rule
```

The docs also describe how to change a crush rule and modify the crushmap. Changing the data placement will cause a remapping of the PGs, depending on your ceph version it will remap 5% of misplaced PGs at max. The remapping process can be controlled with these osd config settings:

```
osd_recovery_max_active
osd_max_backfills
```

Set them to higher values to increase the recovery speed, but set them back to the defaults after you're finished.